# Low pressure on hot water, no cold water, frozen pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

We woke up yesterday to no cold water running in our basement toilet and shower. There is no cold water and very low pressure on the hot water. We had extremely low temperature outside (-24 Celsius) during the night, so our first guest was that it was a frozen pipe, so we left the hot water running and we heated up the bathroom with an external/heater. Note that we have a faucet in the same room and we have full water pressure for both cold and hot water. No issue elsewhere in our house.

+20 hours later, we still have the low pressure on the hot water line and no water on the cold line. The water coming in at the end of the hot water line is hot.

I'm starting to think it's not a frozen pipe for these reason:

1) The working water faucet is the one on the external wall, the shower and toilet are on an internal wall. It's still possible that's it's frozen between the faucet and the shower/toilet section

2) After running for +20 hours, the hot pipe still has a low pressure. I would have expected the hot water pipe to have at least unfrozen with all the hot running water running continuously for this long.

Any idea ? What could it be ? How can we explain that the hot water pipe is still "frozen" after running with hot water for so long ? Thanks !

Comment: So I figured out something with the hot water. If I don't fully open the shower valve and I set it at 50%, I'm actually able to get very good pressure for hot water. So if I understand correctly, hot water is ok and not frozen, it only needs some air that usually come from the cold water pipe. So basically, I think I only have a classic cold water pipe frozen and nothing is wrong with the hot water pipe.

Comment: So, what we ended up doing is eating the exposed copper pipe in order to get the water inside hotter. The pipe has now unfroze and we can use it.